# Transition bug in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

And to the point, in one of my apps client got a transition bug, in chrome, latest version - when he loads the page css transtions are not working at all, then , when he scrolls, or does some different stuff for some time transitions are back on, and some time later they are not working again ([Video of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao6GAx2q7XA&feature=youtu.be)). Transition example:

```
 -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
 -ms-transition: all .3s linear;
 -o-transition: all .3s linear;
 transition: all .3s linear;
```

And the [site](http://agrodev.monamiadv.com.ua/) itself.
P.S. I can't reproduce bug on my pc, or any pc I have access to, but client have it on 2 of 5 pc. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe different platform on client side? Mac for example?

Comment: @Morpheus Nop, It's all windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two computers out of fifty that have this Chrome bug too.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756

This is fixed in version 40.0.2214.115

Answer (score 0):

I saw in your stylesheet that you `:hover` selector set on `:after` pseudoselector,
 for ex. (line 468 style.css):

```
 .news ul li a:hover:after
```

On some chrome versions that might not work , to make it work you need to declare the hover by itself;

try:

```
 .news ul li a:hover {} 
 .news ul li a:hover:before { /* This works (needs :hover declared) */ }
```

I couldn't reproduce the bug muself because I believe this was fixed on new chrome versions_

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it, but the thing is not only the pseudo elements transitions are not working, but all the transitions , even if it's `height` or `border-radius`. And client has the latest chrome, so if it''s older version bug, probably not it.

Comment: if he experiences it on just some PCs they might not all be updated, try and and let me know if it fixes it..